# Can i use the shortcut sign $ and jQuery together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to validate a form before submitting.The validation works fine but the form is not submitting.I don't have enough knowledge about jQuery but i am suspecting this is for using the shortcut  $ and jQuery together,am i right or the problem is elsewhere ?

CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $('p select[name=country]').change(function(){
  if ($('p select[name=country]').val() =='Au')
  {
  $('#seldivi').show();
  }

else
    {
    $('#seldivi').hide();
    }
});



        $(function(){
    $("a.mytrigger").click(function(e){
        var index = $(this).attr("href").substr(5);
        $('#navigation li:nth-child('+parseInt(index)+') a').click();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

//when i remove the following segment of codes the form submitted as usual but when  this portion exists the form is not submitted  

            jQuery(function(){
                jQuery("#ValidField").validate({
                    expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Please enter the Required field"
                });
                jQuery("#ValidNumber").validate({
                    expression: "if (!isNaN(VAL) && VAL) return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Please enter a valid number"
                });
                jQuery("#ValidInteger").validate({
                    expression: "if (VAL.match(/^[0-9]*$/) && VAL) return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Please enter a valid integer"
                });
                jQuery("#ValidDate").validate({
                    expression: "if (!isValidDate(parseInt(VAL.split('-')[2]), parseInt(VAL.split('-')[0]), parseInt(VAL.split('-')[1]))) return false; else return true;",
                    message: "Please enter a valid Date"
                });
                jQuery("#ValidEmail").validate({
                    expression: "if (VAL.match(/^[^\\W][a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-\\.]+([a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-\\.]+)*\\@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/)) return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Please enter a valid Email ID"
                });
                jQuery("#ValidPassword").validate({
                    expression: "if (VAL.length > 5 && VAL) return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Please enter a valid Password"
                });
                jQuery("#ValidConfirmPassword").validate({
                    expression: "if ((VAL == jQuery('#ValidPassword').val()) && VAL) return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Confirm password field doesn't match the password field"
                });
                jQuery("#ValidSelection").validate({
                    expression: "if (VAL != '0') return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Please make a selection"
                });
                jQuery("#ValidMultiSelection").validate({
                    expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Please make a selection"
                });
                jQuery("#ValidRadio").validate({
                    expression: "if (isChecked(SelfID)) return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Please select a radio button"
                });
                jQuery("#ValidCheckbox").validate({
                    expression: "if (isChecked(SelfID)) return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Please check atleast one checkbox"
                });


   });
            /* ]]> */
```

Comment: Yes, you can use them together. `$` is just an alias for `jQuery`.

Comment: if so why the form is only submitted when i remove the specified part of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long answer short : $ is an alias of the function jQuery so you can use both.

I you want to make sure it's the right problem, use jQuery everywhere instead of $ and read about jQuery.noConflict(). That might fix your problem if you are using multiple libraries that use $.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/